# Issue when I want to import CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I want to import users with a CSV file so I put this code in lib/task/import.rake :

```
require 'csv'    

task :import => :environment do
  CSV.foreach('db/test.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    UserManager::User.create!(row.hash)
  end
end
```

Here is my CSV test file :

```
surname;name;email;password;password_confirmation
test;test;test@exemple.fr;pass;pass
```

And when I run `rake import` I get this error :

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

Why did I get this error ?

Comment: it should be `row.to_hash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up the comment of Pavan and the solution of gunn, your code should be:

```
require 'csv'    

task :import => :environment do
  CSV.foreach('db/test.csv', :headers => true, col_sep: ';') do |row|
    UserManager::User.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Those variables aren't comma separated, they're semicolon separated. So:

```
CSV.foreach('db/test.csv', headers: true, col_sep: ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
require 'csv'    

task :import => :environment do
  CSV.foreach('db/test.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    UserManager::User.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

`row.hash` will return an integer

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
        require 'csv'

        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: false) do |row|
         user_hash = {}
         user_hash = {"surname"=> name,"last_name"=> last_name }  #key value 
         User.create!(user_hash)
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ............

```
    require 'csv'
    #file with full path
    file = "#{Rails.root}/public/file_name.csv"

    #Reading file
    user_file = CSV.read(file, :headers => true)

    #Creating User

    user = UserManager::User.where(:email => user_file['email']).first_or_create

   if user.present?
     user.name = user_file['email']
     #Same other data ......
     user.save!
   end
```

Hope this will work for you.